# Formalization of the meaning of "simplify"ing algebraic expressions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, soft-question

Do there exist any formal definition of the *simplification* of algebraic expressions? For example one can perform the calculations

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)} = \frac a {1+x} + \frac b {1-x} = \frac{a-ax+b+bx}{1-x^2}$$

$$\cases{a+b=1\\b-a=0} \Leftrightarrow \cases{a=1/2\\b=1/2}$$

Who decides whether $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ or $\frac{1/2}{1-x} + \frac{1/2}{1+x}$ is the "simplest"?

Should one not talk about simplification with respect to a cost function or minimizing total number of some operations?

If a division costs me $d$, a multiplication $m$ an addition $a$ and a subtraction $s$ then we can calculate which is "cheapest". But is that what we want "simplify" to mean or is it something else?

Comment: It depends utterly on context.  If you are trying to integrate, $\frac{1/2}{1-x} + \frac{1/2}{1+x}$ (or even $\frac{1}{2} ( \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1+x})$) might be considered "more simple."  On the other hand, $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}$ might be considered "more simple" if the goal is to graph the rational function by hand, and $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ might be considered "more simple" if differentiation is the goal.  Aesthetics also play a role (which is "simpler": $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?).

Comment: Interesting observations. I wonder why so many exercises in school say "simplify" without providing any context, objective or aesthetic taste. I can't remember making that observation back when I did those exercises.

Comment: I suspect that the topic of the class makes the context universal to that class.  For example, in a precalc class the goal is to teach students symbol manipulation, and it is generally easier to manipulate expressions with fewer symbols.  Thus the job of "simplifying" is to reduce the number of symbols running around.  On the other hand, the goal of a course on integration is to compute integrals, in which case "simplifying" comes down to what is easier to integrate.  In any event, I might argue that the instruction "Simplify!" is not entirely clear, and requires more context.